# (MSDN)Make thread "alertable" constantly without blocking the thread

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, msdn, overlapped-io

I am using asynchronous process calls (APC) to do overlap I/O requests using  ReadFileEx and WriteFileEx. As defined in MSDN, these function's completion routines(APCs) will only be handled if the thread, which defines APCs, is under "alertable" state.

Examples from [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/parallel-programming-with-c-part-1-asynchronous-procedure-calls) and [there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060503-11/?p=31323) both use SleepEx() function to keep the thread alertable by doing `SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE)`, so that the thread will stay in alertable state infinitely till all the APCs are completed, which means the thread is suspended till all the APCs are done. Doesn't this violate the reason we use overlapped I/O, ReadFileEx and WriteFileEx? I thought the whole idea is to make thread responsive and put time-consuming in background. Please help me explain the idea.

Although, in the first link, it mentions we can use `SleepEx(0,TRUE)` to make thread return immediately and can handle the APCs at the same time, I still don't know what to do in the period before the APCs return and how to know when they will return. My goal is merely keep thread responsive, but nothing to do.

Comment: It's not the only way to handle Asynchronous IO completion. you can poll the state of the IO with `GetOverLappedResult` and you can play with IO-completion ports to create a reactor/proactor pattern

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the thread responsive?"  What does the thread do?  How is it assigned work items?

Comment: if you mean ui thread - you need use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjectsex) with `MWMO_ALERTABLE`. with this you can process windows messages and apc

Comment: @DavidHaim hi, I would like to know what GetOverlappedResult can do in my case which uses Read/WriteFileEx with completion routines?thanks

Comment: @PeterRuderman The thread has to remain responsive and update a progress bar while reading and writing files at the same time.

Comment: @DavidHaim I will check that function, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking here, but I'll take a stab at it.

Whether waiting for APCs negates the benefits of doing asynchronous I/O depends entirely on your design.  If you wrote something like:

```
WriteFileEx(..., &overlapped, CompleteWrite);
SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);
```

Then clearly you haven't accomplished anything aside from over-complicating your program.  You might as well do synchronous I/O.

But you could also write something like:

```
while (work_to_do)
{
  DoSomeWork();
  WriteFileEx(results);
  SleepEx(0, TRUE);
}
```

Now you've avoided some down time.  If the WriteFileEx takes a long time to complete, the thread can continue doing work in the interim.

You might also create a thread that services requests.  Something like:

```
DWORD ThreadProc(...)
{
  while (!done)
  {
    SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);
  }
}
```

This thread just sits around waiting for someone to send it a command using `QueueUserAPC`.  If such a thread issued I/O, it might want to do so asynchronously to allow it to process other commands while waiting for the I/O to complete.  (On the other hand, to avoid re-entrancy issues, it might *not* want to do that.)

I hope this gives some idea how these functions were intended to be used.  But keep in mind that these are *very* old technologies.  You would rarely, if ever, use them in a modern program.  Instead, use functions like `CreateThreadPoolIo`/`StartThreadPoolIo` to have Windows run the I/O completion on a dedicated worker thread for you.  Or better yet, use a higher-level task oriented library and avoid these low level details.

**EDIT - Doing I/O on the main window thread**

The short answer to this particular problem is, don't do it.  Run your I/O on a worker thread and send the results back to the main thread using `PostMessage` or `SendMessage`.  If for some reason you can't do that, then you must use a modified message loop.  Instead of `GetMessage`, use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, that will let you process window messages while waiting for the I/O to complete.

```
// error checking omitted
OVERLAPPED overlapped{};
ReadFile(file_handle, buffer, bytes_to_read, &bytes_read, &overlapped);

while (true)
{
  DWORD wait_result = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(
    1,
    &file_handle,
    FALSE,
    INFINITE,
    QS_ALLINPUT);

  if (wait_result = WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    // I/O completed...
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am current using the same way as you did in the "while(work_to_do)..." and this is my point asking the question. When we put a while loop in the main thread, that is equally freezing the main thread which violates my purpose of doing overlapped io request.

Comment: I see what you're after now.  I'll update my answer.